# How to calling javascriprt function in laravel blade after mix

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-mix

in here i have stuck mind and cannot found how to solve this

i have a file `app.js` & `form.js`

in `app.js` i have some code like:

```
require('bootsrap');
require('./form.js');
```

in `form.js` i have function code like:

```
function saveform(somevariable) {
 // some code
}
```

then mix that `app.js`  file

after that i'm call `saveform(somevariable)` function into laravel blade file
lets we call as `form.blade.php`

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>

 <script>
   var somvariable = 'some attribute';
   
   saveform(somevariable);
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

and i have and error like this in browser

```
ReferenceError: saveform is not function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use window

in `app.js`

```js
require('bootsrap');
window.form = require('./form.js');
```

in `form.js`

```
export function saveform(somevariable) {
 // some code
}
```

in `form.blade.php`

```html
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>
  <script>
   var somvariable = 'some attribute';
   
   window.form.saveform(somevariable);
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i'm still got an error like `Uncaught TypeError: window.form.saveform is not a function`

Comment: thanks, its work, the file require must be following name file, like if file `form.js` its must be `window.form` or if file `_form.js` its must be `window._form`